# I would like to understand vue.js components and databinding with userinteractions, Can anyone correct my code and explain it to me?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm a beginner developer , currently I'm working on a weather app project with vue.js . I have some problems with components and databinding with vue. Can anyone explain it to me with some code sample?!

I've read some forums, and watched some tutorial videos about custom components , tried it as well but i think I made some mistakes.
Specificly i would like to know, how can i bind my API url data to a dropdown box, that the location changes with every selection.

note: Used API is an open weather API, based on latitude and longitude locations.

```js
var myDropdown = Vue.component('my-dropdown', {
  template: '#dropdown',
data: function() {
  return {
    isOpen: false,
    selected: null,
    options: [
      'Heidenheim an der Brenz',
      'Giengen',
      'Ulm',
    ]
  }
},
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    },
    show: function() {
      this.isOpen = true;
    },
    hide: function() {
      this.isOpen = false;
    },
  set: function(option) {
    this.selected = option;
    this.hide();
  }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log('My dropdown component is mounted!')
  }
});

let weatherApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   town: '',
    Temp: '',
    minTemp: '',
    maxTemp:'',
    wind: '',
    description: '', 
    icon: '',
    hdh: 'https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=48.6833&lon=10.15',
    ulm: 'https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=48.39841&lon=9.99155',
    giengen: 'https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=48.39841&lon=9.99155'
  },
  methods: {
    getWeather() {
    var url = '';
      axios
        .get(url)
        .then(response => {
         this.town = response.data.name
          this.Temp = response.data.main.temp;
          this.minTemp = response.data.main.temp_min;
          this.maxTemp = response.data.main.temp_max;
          this.wind = response.data.wind.speed;
          this.description = response.data.weather[0].description;
          this.icon = response.data.weather[0].icon;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.getWeather();
  },
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url(https://shiftyjelly.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/w.jpg?w=960&h=400);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 960px;
  height: 400px;
}

#weather {
  padding: 15px;
}

#temperature {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 240px;
  left: 420px;
  color: black;
}

#temp-values {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  text-justify: distribute;
  display: block;
  top: 60px;
  left: -200px;
  color: black;
}

#info {
  padding: 15px;
}

#name {
  top: 10px;
  left: 300px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.wind {
  top: 180px;
  left: 380px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
}

#icon {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: -180px;
  top: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

#my-dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  min-width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
}


#selected {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: rgba(05, 46, 41, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: 1.25rem/40px 'Ubuntu', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000;
  color: rgb(0, 237, 255);
}


#selected: after {
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  content: '▼';
  color: black;
}

#selected:hover: after {
  opacity: 1;
}

#options {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3px;
  background: rgba(05, 46, 41, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#option {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font: 1.2rem 'Vollkorn', Georgia, Times, serif;
  color: rgb(0, 237, 255);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000;
}


#option:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}


#option:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}


#fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
#fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.5;
 transform: translateY(-30px);
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.js"></script>
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
<template id="dropdown">
  <div id="my-dropdown">
  <div id="selected" @click="toggle">Select Your Town Here</div>
    <div id="options" v-show="isOpen">
    <div id="option" v-for="option in options" @click="set(option)">
      {{ option }}
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
  <body>
   <div id="app">
   <my-dropdown></my-dropdown>
  <div id="weather">
    <span id="name">{{town}}</span>
    <span id="icon">{{description}}</span>
    <span id="temperature">{{Temp}}°</span><br>
    <span id="temp-values">Min: {{minTemp}}° <br> Max: {{maxTemp}}°</span>
  </div>
  <div id="info">
    <img class="wind" height="40px" width="40px" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/71601/wind.svg"> 
    <span class="wind">{{wind}} m/s</span>
  </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/skomq0zj/)

First, it's best to keep all of your data in one place rather than hard-coding the town names in the dropdown component.  You also don't need to store the whole url each time.  So remove `options` from the dropdown. You'll pass the town data to it via prop.

1) Restructure your app's town data into an array of objects like this:

```
data: {
  ...
  towns: [
    {abbr: 'hdh', name: 'Heidenheim an der Brenz', lat: '48.6833', lon: '10.15'},
    {abbr: 'ulm', name: 'Ulm', lat: '48.39841', lon: '9.99155'},
    {abbr: 'giengen', name: 'Giengen', lat: '48.39841', lon: '9.99155'}
  ]
}
```

2) Pass the town data via prop named "options" to the dropdown component:

```
<my-dropdown :options="towns"></my-dropdown>
```

3) Change the dropdown label to `{{ option.name }}`

4) Add the prop to the component:

```
props: ['options']
```

5) Emit a custom event when the town changes:

```
set: function(option) {
  this.$emit('change-town', option);
  ...
}
```

6) Process that event in the parent template's `getWeather`:

```
<my-dropdown :options="towns" @change-town="getWeather"></my-dropdown>
```

7) Generate the URL and send the request:

```
getWeather(option) {
  const urlpath = 'https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?'
  const qs = `lat=${option.lat}&lon=${option.lon}`;
  const url = path + qs;
  axios.get(url)...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. helped a lot.